# Avoid code duplication when writing selenium tests for Firefox and Chrome

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, firefox, design-patterns, dry

If you write tests for Selenium to check e.g. both Firefox and Chrome, the tests look very much alike, except for the setUp, see e.g. https://gist.github.com/devinmancuso/54904c005f8d237f6fec, which has identical functions `test_search_in_python_chrome` and `test_search_in_python_firefox`. There are patterns to avoid code duplication in selenium, e.g. [the Page Object Pattern](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageObjects).

Is there a way to avoid this huge code duplication?

Comment: Would the @close-voter be so kind as to explain his reasoning, or not?

Comment: I'm assuming the close voter was expecting you to put your code in the question itself (and you should). One day you may delete that repo or change it completely, then this question has no context. A [mcve] should be in the question. A second point could be made that question is off topic on SO since you have working code. You are really asking for a code review which belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @JeffC: the linked code came up when searching, I had only some ugly stuff that did not work: I exended from TestCase with the base class, which failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of `setUp` in the link you provided is the `driver` initialization. You can handle this in another class and reed the browser type from property file

```
def get_driver(self):
    browser = get_value_from_configurations_file()
    url = get_value_from_configurations_file()

    driver = None
    if browser == 'chrome':
         driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    elif browser == 'firefox':
         driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url)

    return driver
```

I usually use a "middle man" between the driver factory and the tests to handle the `driver` actions and get PO starting point

```
class WebApplication:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__driver = WebDriverFactory().get_driver()

    def get_driver(self):
        return self.__driver

    def get_home_page(self):
        return HomePage(self.__driver)
```

And use it from base test class

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("run_for_test")
class AbstractTest(ABC):

    web_application = None

    @pytest.fixture()
    def run_for_test(self, request):
        AbstractTest.web_application = WebApplication()
        # set up for all tests
        yield
        # tear down for all tests
```

Example test:

```
class TestExample(AbstractTest):

    def test_example(self):
        home_page = \
            (self.web_application
             .get_home_page())
```

That way you can write the test once and run it on different browsers by simply changing the configurations file.

Comment: One thing I would add to this is that the two tests are basically the same so one should be removed. The driver manager will take care of the driver instance, whether it's firefox or chrome. I think you addressed this indirectly but I would explicitly state this to make it clear since OP is asking for this feedback. One other minor comment is on the screenshot code (the last line of the test)... I would remove the browser name and add a timestamp so that later sshots don't overwrite earlier ones.

Comment: @JeffC I edited my answer based on your first comment. About the second comment I agree, but it's not the point here (and personally I will have the screenshot taken from the PO), so I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

@Guy's answer showed the direction. [A solution](https://github.com/serv-inc/safe-search/blob/master/test/functional_test.py) that is a bit simpler is to use `MixIns`:

```
class DuckMixin(object):
    def testDuckLoads(self):
        self.browser.get("https://duckduckgo.com")
        self.assertIn("duckduckgo", self.browser.title.lower())

    def testDuckSafe(self):
        self.browser.get("https://duckduckgo.com")
        (self.browser
         .find_element_by_id("search_form_input_homepage")
         .send_keys("porn" + webdriver.common.keys.Keys.RETURN))
        # click to disable temporarily, then wait, then see if available
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("js-safe-search-temp").click()
        # assert that browser.find_element_by_class_name("js-safe-search-temp") still exists, else throws exception
        self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("js-safe-search-temp")


class DuckDuckGoTestCaseFirefox(unittest.TestCase, DuckMixin):
    def setUp(self):
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.add_extension(extension=os.path.join(DIR, "..", "addon"))
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.close()

class DuckDuckGoTestCaseChromium(unittest.TestCase, DuckMixin):
    def setUp(self):
        profile = webdriver.chrome.options.Options()
        profile.add_extension(extension=os.path.join(DIR, "..", "safe.zip"))
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=profile)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.close()
```